# Modal em component separados

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Olá, sou novo em Bootstrap com angular, e gostaria de saber se à uma maneira de criar um modal em um component e chamá-lo em outro, por exemplo:

Component-pai
component-modal

dai o component pai teria um botão que chamaria o component-modal.

Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie o modal no Component-modal.html

Use *ngIf no Component-pai.html

```
<button (click)="adicioneComponentModal()">Adicione Component Modal</button>
<component-modal *ngIf="modals != null"></component-modal>
```

No Component-pai.ts

```
modals: ComponentModal = null;

adicioneComponentModal() {
    this.modals = new ComponentModal();
}
```